# VSCode terminal in ubuntu wsl

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I've run into an issue where when I open vscode through WSL (command code.) it opens VSCode with no terminal whatsoever and there's no option to open one.

Terminal on WSL Ubuntu:

[image: Terminal on WSL Ubuntu]

But when I run vscode from Windows I do have the option to use my Ubuntu terminal

Terminal on Windows:

[image: Terminal on Windows]

Has anyone had similar issues? Did I miss a setting somewhere in VSCode?

Comment: What happens when you click on `Select default profile` in WSL? It might have something to do with the default profiles available

Comment: on windows it lists all possible terminals and asks which I'd like to use as default, on wsl it lists nothing

Comment: That's odd. Can you try adding this to your `settings.json` in WSL: `"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash"
        }
    }`
Restart VSCode and see if you'll see anything in `Select default profile`